# STM32F0 Capacitive Touch Not Detecting

Tags: capacitor, stm32, touchscreen

I am trying to implement a simple capacitive touch sensor using the STM32F0's TSC peripheral. I currently have the following setup. **(PA1 and PA2 are switched in the schematic, accidentally)**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faoIGa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I use the following function to set up the TSC peripheral.

```
void setupTSC() {
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0x2 << (2*1)) + (0x2 << (2*2)); //enable AF for PA1 and PA2
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (0x3 << (4*1)) + (0x3 << (4*2)); //enable AF3 for PA1 and PA2
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_TSEN;
    TSC->IER |= 0x01; //enable end of acquisition interrupt
    TSC->IOSCR |= 0x04; //enable G1_IO3 (PA2) as sampling capacitor
    TSC->IOCCR |= 0x02; //enable G1_IO2 (PA1) as channel
    TSC->IOGCSR |= 0x01; //enable G1 analog group
    TSC->IOHCR &= ~(0x06); //disable hysteresis on PA1 and PA2 
    //TSC->IOASCR |= 0x04; //do I need this?
    NVIC->ISER[0] |= 1 << TS_IRQn; //enable TSC interrupt
    TSC->CR |= 0x01 + 0x00C0 + 0x02; //enable TSC and start acquisition
}
```

And then use the following interrupt handler for when acquisition is completed.

```
void TS_IRQHandler() {
    char s[16];
    itoa(TSC->IOGXCR[0], s, 10);
    TSC->ICR |= 0x03; //clear interrupts
    writeLine(1, s); //prints s to LCD so I can verify delay
    TSC->CR |= 0x02; //restart acquisition
}
```

However, no matter what I do, the TSC always counts up to the maximum value (16383 with my configuration). I have tried using larger and smaller electrodes, replacing the electrode with a capacitor to ground (to test), but nothing works, which makes me think my setup is incorrect. What's going wrong here?

My oscilloscope shows that both the sampling capacitor and electrode are charging, but the count register never returns anything other than the maximum value.

Comment: Writing directly against the registers is challenging as there is so much that can go wrong.  See if you can find a canned HAL-based example for a Discovery or Nucleo F0 and try that, then once it works start comparing how that manipulates the registers to what you are doing until you figure out the difference.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've tried finding examples, and [this](https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-l073RZ/system/src/stm32l0xx/stm32l0xx_hal_tsc.c) was about the closest I came, and yes, it uses the HAL. However, after comparing, it seems as though my initialization is identical, so I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Find the source mentioned in AN4735 and actually build and try it.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong, it's enabling G1_IO4 (PA3) not G1_IO3 (PA2) as intended.

```
TSC->IOSCR |= 0x04; //enable G1_IO3 (PA2) as sampling capacitor
```

I don't use IOASCR in my working setup, you can see the counter output below, low count = insulated electrode touched. I'd show you my code but I don't use C
and you probably don't use Forth.

```
 4887 
 4868 
 4838 
 4721 
 705 
 483 
 461 
 455 
 451 
 447 
 444 
 443 
 441 
 441 
 500 
 4853 
 4921
```